# Rails log for rspec tests inside of an engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, rspec, rails-engines, guard

I am having trouble in understanding how can I check the logs for a test inside of an engine.
So My setup is the typical example, with a main app and engine. Inside of the engine I have a dummy application(inside the rspec folder) that I use to test my engine.

Now I am construction a lib file and would like to test it. This lib is a communication system to an API and I am getting problems when communicating but it's weird since I have another application making the same requests to the same API and it works. So I wanted to check the logs for the tests(so I can see the request and the messages being passed to the API).

My first thought was to look for a log folder at the engine, which does not exist???
second I thought maybe the main application(just to clear that out of the way), obviously the logs there were not logging anything.
Then I thought it could make sense if the dummy application had some logs and it does. The test.log, but that does not log anything.

Now just as detail, I am running my tests with guard & rspec.

let me know if you have some light on this or any other thoughts that could help.

all the best,

Andre

Comment: what is the `terminal output` you got while running `rspec` command in terminal?

Comment: what you mean? my tests run with rspec or guard. they are working, but failing and I wanna find out why, that's why I would like to look at the log to see the requests, json msgs, etc...

Comment: where would you run guard command or spec command?

Comment: Inside my engine's path!

Comment: did you able to see anything after execute `spec path/to/your_spec_file.rb`

Comment: I dont think you have read my question here! My specs are successful! they run! the only reasons the test fail has to do with my own code or the external API not working correctly. That's why I wanna look at the  logs! why you keep asking me what I get after running the specs? I dont understand your point